# How to fix the error The type 'IObjectContainer' exists in both

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

The problem arose after the transition from the version SpecFlow 3.0 to Specflow 2.4.0

```
[Binding]
public class Hooks 
{
    private readonly IObjectContainer _objectContainer;

    public Hooks(IObjectContainer objectContainer)
    {
        _objectContainer = objectContainer;
    }
}
```

> Error  CS0433  The type 'IObjectContainer' exists in both 'BoDi, Version=1.4.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ff7cd5ea2744b496' and 'TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41'

Close Visual Studio and clear bin and obj folders in your project directory - 
did not help

How does the image solve the current problem?

Answer (score 2):

SpecFlow 2.4 has the BoDi- Library included. In SpecFlow 3.0 it is a NuGet dependency.
You have probably somewhere still the BoDi- Library added as a NuGet package. Try to remove it and build again.